# AngularJS: How to use ng-repeat to display all elements of an array contained in a parent array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The HTML doesn't work. I want to display ALL those letters in the array where the `<h4>` tag is. My access isn't working. How do I fix this?

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 words" ng-repeat="choice in images[num].letters">
    <h4>{{choice}}</h4>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    $scope.num = 0;
    $scope.images = 
    [ 

    { pics: ["img/carrion.png", "img/telefrag.png", "img/thunder-skull.png", "img/skull-ring.png"], word: 'skull', length: 5, 
    'letters': ['u', randLet(), randLet(), randLet(), 's', randLet(), 'k', 'l', randLet(), randLet(), randLet(), 'l' ]},

    { pics: ["img/angry-eyes.png", "img/behold.png", "img/spectacle-lenses.png", "img/falling-eye.png"], word: 'eye', length: 3},
    ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to resolve this problem for duplicate data  use track by $index. like this code

```
<div ng-repeat="choice in images[num].letters track by $index">
        <h4>{{choice}}</h4>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you woud need to do is nest another `ng-repeat` within this div

```
<div class="col-sm-6 words" ng-repeat="choice in images[num].letters">
    <h4>{{choice}}</h4>
</div>
```

something like

```
<div class="col-sm-6 words" ng-repeat="image in images">
    <div ng-repeat="propValue in image">
      {{propValue}}
    </div>
</div>
```

In this instance image in images is iterating over each object in your images array. The next ng-repeat is iterating over the property values of each individual object. Hopefully that makes sense and helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

Replace with below.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 words" ng-repeat="image in images">
  <div ng-repeat="choice in image.letters">
     <h4>{{choice}}</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I get when running your code is the code breaking on duplicate values in the ng-repeat (i.e. "l" and "l"). Maybe there is a better way around it, but here is my working solution:

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ctrl.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="lettersCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="letter in images[num].letters">
        <h4>{{ letter[0] }}</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### ctrl.js

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('lettersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.num = 0;
  $scope.images = [ 
    {
      pics: ["img/carrion.png", "img/telefrag.png", "img/thunder-skull.png", "img/skull-ring.png"],
      word: 'skull',
      length: 5, 
      letters: ['u', 's', 'k', 'l1', 'l2']
    },
    {
      pics: ["img/angry-eyes.png", "img/behold.png", "img/spectacle-lenses.png", "img/falling-eye.png"],
      word: 'eye',
      length: 3
    }
  ];
});
```

I would create a function to loop through all the letters and add a number of the occurrence before updating outputting the data.

Answer (score 0):

'letters': ['u', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'k', 'y', 'f', 'g', 'm', 'l']

Please check your randLet() is there duplicated letters.this is the problem.